# Installing Python imaging library (PIL) on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

Something that probably shouldn't be causing me so many problems, is.

I'm trying to install PIL on my Ubuntu server. It's installing fine. However every time I try and update the database to add the image field I get the following error:

Error: One or more models did not validate:
product.product: "image": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .

I've just realised I have been logged in as my user. Do i need to be logged in as root to install it? I'm doing this on a VPS not a local machine.

I've tried loads of tutorials on the web and not getting anywhere at all.

Comment: Is this Django's `ImageField` ?

Comment: It seems unlikely you have rights to install modules into the system site-packages if you're not logged in as root. If you're not allowed to, you might wanna setup a virtualenv and go from there

Comment: Thankyou.. I have setup a virtualenv for my site. I originally installed it within the virtualenv (However i think it installed to the main system). How would I go about installing it to the virtualenv?

Comment: Activate your virtualenv, "source yourenv/bin/activate" then install PIL. You might also want to install yolk, it's a helpful tool to quickly list your packages, locations and current versions

Comment: Thanks, i've now tried it within the virtualenv and it seems to try and install it then i get this error back - 

_imaging.c:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Have a look: https://github.com/dharmafly/tasket/issues/258

Comment: Args, thanks for your help. I had to install python-dev, not sure why but i needed this for it to install inside my virtualenv.

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had to install python-dev then install PIL inside my virtualenv.

All working now.

Thanks for your help all! :)

Comment: and first, apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev to get jpeg support

Answer (score 4):

If you are not root, then entering the following command should install python-imaging:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

Or (if you are root), the following command (without sudo) will install python-imaging

```
apt-get install python-imaging
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've tried both of these commands and this is message I get back:

python-imaging is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.

Comment: That means that you have PIL already installed in your system; you need not to install it anymore

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be using a `virtualenv` and `pip install pil` there... If you have access and want to use system wide packages, then you need to elevate to root (sudo) to `easy_install` or `pip` install.

Make sure your server (Django?) is rebooted so it can pick up the new libraries. (The interpreter doesn't always seem to pick up newly installed modules while it's running).